# ¿como regresar datos desde una base a una web, con la sintaxis moderna de PHP7?

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb

Veran, yo ya sabia como conectarme a msqli, hacer una consulta y retornar los datos a una pagina web, pero, revisando el manual de php me he enterado de que los metodos que usaba para hacer esto ya son obsoletos en PHP7. Dice: **"Aliases and deprecated Mysqli Functions"**. Por ejemplo yo usaba para conectarme esto:

```
mysqli_connect( 'localhost','root','pass', 'database' ) or die ( "error" )
```

Pero ahora dicen que debe ser esto:

```
new mysqli( '', '', '', '' )
```

Entonces, estoy aprendiendo a conectarme con una base de dato y a hacer consultas de la forma "moderna", como objeto..Y ya aprendi como conectarme y como hacer una consulta, pero, aun no logro saber como retornar datos desde una base.. antes lo hacia con FETCH_ARRAY, pero con esta forma moderna, no logro encontrar un tutorial donde se explique bien..Por eso quisiera que me ayuden con esto ¿como retorno datos de una base con la sintaxis moderna de PHP7? y ¿es cierto que la anterior ya esta obsoleta?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como dice el mensaje que te arroja PHP 7, efectivamente hay algunos alias de mysqli que son obsoletos, [aquí tienes la lista de todos ellos](http://php.net/manual/es/ref.mysqli.php).

Entre esos alias se encuentra la función de conexión a mysqli que estás usando.

Para **modernizar** tu código, puedes usar el estilo orientado a objetos, el cual consistirá en dos cosas esenciales:

- Para crear la conexión a `mysqli` crear una instancia de la clase mediante `new`
- Para todas las funciones relativas a la conexión usar la sintaxis:

  - `$objeto->metodo()`
  - `$objeto->propiedad`

#### Ejemplos concretos

```
/*Crear la conexión*/
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'tu_user', 'tu_password', 'tu_db');

/*Usar la conexión para una consulta*/

$sql="SELECT * FROM tabla";
$resultado = $mysqli->query($sql);

/*Usar la propiedad num_rows*/
echo $resultado->num_rows;

/*Cerrar la conexión*/
$mysqli->close();
```

En todo el código hemos usado el estilo orientado a objetos, que consiste en `$objeto->metodo()`.

> **NOTA MUY IMPORTANTE**: Todas las funciones del Manual de PHP te explican siempre los dos estilos. Y cada explicación es muy clara: hay
>   siempre dos apartados, uno que dice: **Estilo orientado a objetos** y
>   otro que dice **Estilo por procedimientos**. Como es evidente, debes
>   optar por el primero.

Podemos ver el caso por el que preguntas precisamente, [`fetch_array` en el Manual de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php).

Primero te muestran cómo usar ese método con el estilo orientado a objetos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y luego te explican su uso con el estilo por procedimientos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Todas las funciones son explicadas del mismo modo, mostrando cómo se usan con cada estilo de programación.

---

### Ejemplo de obtención de datos

La obtención de datos puede variar, de acuerdo al tipo de consulta que ejecutes: (SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE...). En la consultas del tipo `SELECT` por lo general te interesan los datos que trae esa consulta en sí. Para las otras consultas pueden interesar la cantidad de filas afectadas por ellas.

Incluso dentro de las consultas `SELECT`, la obtención de datos también depende de si esperas una sola fila, varias filas, de si usas consultas preparadas o no... En este punto particular mysqli es un poco más complicado que PDO por motivos que no explico ahora para no alejarme demasiado del tema principal.

Dado que la forma de obtener datos puede ser diversa, por lo explicado más arriba, te mostraré dos formas que son las más usuales, y usando `query` simplemente, no voy a meterme con las consultas preparadas porque el tema es algo más complejo.

#### Obtener datos usando `query` si esperamos una sola fila

```
$sql = "SELECT nombre, apellido FROM persona LIMIT 1";
if ($resultado = $mysqli->query($sql)) {
    $fila=$resultado->fetch_assoc();
    echo $fila["nombre"];
    echo $fila["apellido"];
}else{
    echo "Error en la consulta: ".$mysqli->error;
}
```

#### Obtener datos usando `query` si esperamos varias filas

```
$sql = "SELECT nombre, apellido FROM persona";
if ($resultado = $mysqli->query($sql)) {
    while ($fila = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo $fila["nombre"];
        echo $fila["apellido"];
    }
}else{
    echo "Error en la consulta: ".$mysqli->error;
}
```

¿Qué diferencia hay entre el primer código y el segundo? En el segundo hay un `while` y en el primero no. Lo he puesto así a propósito, para explicar que, por lo general cuando se hace una consulta a la base de datos, PHP no te trae todos los datos de golpe (a no ser que se lo indiques de forma explícita). PHP hace esto para no saturar la memoria en caso de consultas que pueden retornar miles o millones de datos. El código a través de la API mysqli conecta con la base de datos y te deja activo algo así como un puntero para que recorras los datos (por eso el `while`). Lo que hace el código en teoría es ir aplicando a cada fila del puntero el método indicado (en este caso `fetch_assoc`), trayendo los datos según ese método.

Dado que `fetch_assoc` crea un arreglo asociativo, podemos obtener cada dato haciendo `$fila["columna"]`.

La lectura / almacenamiento de datos es un mundo, y en todo caso debes aplicar lo que mejor de convenga. En este caso los datos fueron impresos con `echo` porque se requería mostrarlos *in situ*, pero si necesitaras los datos para pasarlos a otra parte (desde una llamada a un método), entonces en vez de imprimirlos, tendrías que meterlos en una variable para retornarlos:

```
$sql = "SELECT nombre, apellido FROM persona";
if ($resultado = $mysqli->query($sql)) {
    while ($fila = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
        $allPeople[]= $fila;
    }
}else{
    $allPeople["error"] = "Error en la consulta: ".$mysqli->error;
}
return $allPeople;
```

Aquí, guardamos los datos, o el mensaje de error en el array `$allPeople` y lo retornamos al final. Suponemos que aquí sería un código, función o método que invocado desde otra parte debe retornar el total de personas encontradas o un mensaje de error.

En fin, que obtener datos es un mundo y todo depende siempre de las necesidades que tengas. Aquí ha abordado solamente algo muy básico. Revisa siempre el Manual de PHP usando para cada caso el método o técnica que necesites.

---

### Más cosas a tomar en cuenta

#### Evitar la mezcla de estilos

Otra cosa que debes evitar siempre es la mezcla de estilos. Usa el estilo orientado a objetos en todo tu código, es más moderno, más claro y más intuitivo.

#### Usar siempre el método más específico

Ya que hablamos de `fetch_array`. Algunos programadores cometen el error de usarlo para todo. Pero este método, si no la indicas el *fetch_mode*  de forma explícita puede traerte datos duplicados, en el sentido de que te traerá por cada columna del resultado el mismo dato en una clave numérica del array y en una clave asociativa.

Cuando digo *usar siempre el método más específico*  me refiero a que si necesitas un arreglo asociativo, uses el método `fetch_assoc`, y si necesitas un arreglo numérico uses `fetch_row`.

O, si quieres usar `fetch_array`, indícale mediante un parámetro cómo quieres los datos, para que no se dupliquen y el servidor vaya más cargado.

Comment: Buena explicacion, gracias. Asi queria hacerlo, todo orientado a objetos. Pero sobre "num_rows".. solo me retorna el numero de campos que tengo...9 en mi caso...pero yo quisiera que me retornara el contenido de los campos ¿me dices una funcion como FETCH ARRAY?

Comment: @user104554 puse lo de `num_rows` solamente por explicar cómo se usan las propiedades (que no es lo mismo que los métodos). `num_rows` es una propiedad de la clase `mysqli` que guarda la cantidad de filas encontradas. Para obtener los datos, está explicado en el Manual de PHP, es el enlace que te puse sobre `fetch_array`. Pero ten en cuenta lo que explico al final, sobre usar *Métodos más específicos* para cada cosa. Si no te queda claro, edito la respuesta explicando el uso de alguno de los métodos `fetch`. Pero sería bueno que indiques cómo querrías los resultados.

Comment: Simplemente quiero que cuando haga una consulta especificando los datos de la columna que quiero, me los retorne. Por ejemplo si en una tabla llamada ALUMNOS tengo un campo NAME y otro MAIL, quisiera poder retornar todos los resultados del campo NAME, o tambien todos los resultados de todas las columnas: NAME, MAIL, TLF, etc

Comment: Señor ¿podria revisar por favor el codigo del usuario Shadow (esta mas abajo) para que me diga que le parece su metodo de imprimir los datos desde una base a una web? Lo he probado y funciona bien, pero quisiera otra opinion para saber cual seria el metodo mas adecuado. Ahora estoy haciendo pruebas con ambos.

Comment: @user104554 he editado la respuesta, explicando la forma de obtener los datos. Tomé un ejemplo de los más sencillos, para que puedas entender.

Comment: Excelente explicación. De verdad, muchísimas gracias por tomarse tanto tiempo y por la paciencia. Usted deberia ser profesor. Lo he entendido mejor que en el manual de php.net. Justo le iba a preguntar eso de por que me retornaba un solo dato, pero ya lo resolvi con lo que me enseño del bucle. Y supongo que en ese bucle le puedo poner condiciones para que no me retorne todo, sino por ejemplo solo los 10 primeros campos.

Comment: Sobre SEGURIDAD: Dicen que esta forma (orientada a objetos) es mas segura que la anterior, pero me imagino que a pesar de eso, el programador debe tomar ciertas medidas de seguridad usando funciones reservadas del mismo lenguaje (tal y como cuando programa un formulario) ¿estoy en lo cierto, o ya no es necesario con esta sintaxis?...estoy aprendiendo esto pero sin nada de seguridad. Quisiera que me dijera donde puedo aprender lo basico en caso lo requiera ¿y, es facil?

Comment: @user104554 claro que puedes. Pero recuerda que en mi respuesta hablé sobre la *especificidad*, y eso aplica en todo, también en la lógica de la aplicación. Si sólo necesitas 10 registros entonces en vez de aplicar filtros dentro del bucle, lo que debes hacer es escribir la consulta para que te traiga esos 10 registros que quieres. Como entenderás, hay algo que se llama *recursos* y hay que ahorrar para no saturar la memoria. Si en un código necesitas 10 registros y traes todos los registros (mil, diez mil, cien mil, 1 millón) para luego filtrar esos 10 el código no está optimizado.

Comment: En cuanto a tu duda sobre la **seguridad**, @user104554 lo que piensas es totalmente erróneo. El usar el estilo orientado a objetos no supone ninguna garantía en cuanto a la seguridad. Es solamente un *estilo*, más claro y más moderno. La seguridad se aplica a otro nivel. Por ejemplo, **en toda consulta donde se usen datos que provienen de fuentes externas (formularios, archivos, URL, etc), debes usar consultas preparadas**, por la sencilla razón de que un usuario mal intencionado puede manipular esos datos externos para escribir código malicioso dentro de la consulta...

Comment: Ese es otro tema, y bastante amplio. Aquí hay varias preguntas y respuestas sobre ese tema que te aclararán casi todas las dudas. Puedes buscarlas y leerlas. Busca [sobre *inyección SQL*  aquí mismo en Stackoverflow](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=inyeccion+sql). Hay preguntas y respuestas muy buenas. Además, la inyección SQL es un peligro que puede afectar no solamente a la base de datos, sino a todo el sistema. O sea, a través de SQL, en algunos casos, pueden inyectar en el sistema archivos dañinos (hay una pregunta también que trata sobre ese tema).

Comment: Entiendo. O en ultimo de los casos, contratar a una persona que sepan de seguridad informatica, para que refuerce mi codigo. Pero igual voy a intentar aprender por mi cuenta...Gracias otra vez, muy amable. Voy a guardar este link para repasar la informacion.

Comment: @user104554 Me alegro de que la respuesta te haya ayudado a resolver el problema. Por favor, cuando sea posible l◔_◔: [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) en el Centro de Ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

Para conectarte de manera exitosa con `mysqli` desde PHP deberías hacerlo de este modo; **aunque la extensión mysqli no es moderna, esta desde PHP 5**

```
<?php

$data = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "password", "databaseName");

if(!$data->connect_errno){
  echo "Conectado";
}else{
  return $data->connect_error;
}
```

Si ahora quieres hacer una query y mirar los resultados haz esto

```
$query = $data->query("SELECT * FROM users");

foreach($query as $res)
{
   echo $res["id"];
}
```

Comment: Hola. Para hacer la consulta yo estaba accediendo como objeto...por ejemplo asi $var = new mysqli('', '', ''); $var->query('INSERT INTO bla bla bla')...pero como dije, no se como retornar los datos... O sea lo que quiero hacer es imprimirlos en la pantalla, y que sea de forma permanente ¿como ese foreach es la forma de hacer en PHP7, con la nueva sintaxis? ¿no hay un metodo con el FOREACH?

Comment: No te entiendo, pero ya con el código que te pase no se serás capaz de conectarte, leer sino imprimir datos también, la impresión de hace en el foreach leyendo cada columna @user104554

Comment: Ah, el foreach la imprime... yo pensé que existía un método, o sea una funcion reservada para esa tarea, como la mencionada FETCH_ARRAY..voy a probar el codigo

Comment: Dentro del foreach agrega tantos echo como columnas tengas, si revisas yo puse entre comillas en el echo el nombre de una columna, tú haz lo mismo pero de cada columna que deseas imprimir

Comment: Shadow gracias, tu forma me funciona muy bien. Solo que queria aṕrender tambien la sintaxis orientada a objetos completa. No sabia que se podia hacer con foreach. Estoy probando las dos para ver cual es la mejor.

Comment: shadow, **mezcla de estilos a la vista**: `mysqli_connect_error` y `mysqli_query` son funciones del estilo procedural y `new mysqli()` es estilo orientado a objetos. No se recomienda mezclar los estilos.

Comment: ¿cual seria la sintaxis del CONNECT_ERROR para el estilo orientado a objetos?

Comment: @A.Cedano gracias por la observación no tenia en cuenta que estaba mezclando de manera tan indiscriminada