# Mostrar RAND() LIMIT 5 en php

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Estoy metiendo mando en php para la facu y estoy clavado en algo...
Estoy creando un sistema de sorteo y cuando quiero seleccionar 5 ganadores dentro de un rango, no puedo mostrarlos a todos, solo a uno.

En php:

```php
foreach ($mysqli->query('SELECT * FROM datosprode WHERE resultado = "gana" && fechareg = "05/07/22" ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5 ') as $row){ }
```

Y necesitaría mostrar esos 5 valores aleatorios pero no se como lograrlo

muchas gracias!.

Comment: Lo he probado con una [tabla de ejemplo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=841f6138a2b074e042cf10b7229063f7), sale perfecto el resultado aleatorio y limitado a 5 filas. Lo que debe estar condicionando el output a 1 solo registro es el WHERE y de lo contrario es algo de la programación backend, no creo que sea nada del front.

Comment: en sql también me sale perfecto, le problema es cuando quiero mostrarlo en mi web.
Intente de varias formas pero no le encuentro el caso

Comment: Muestra más contexto. De hecho, no entiendo qué hace un `foreach` encerrando la llamada a `query()` ¿? Mysqli funciona con recursos y tiene sus propios métodos para iterar sobre el recurso que te devuelve `query()`, por eso el `foreach` antes no tiene ningún sentido. Muestra lo que haces en el bloque, dentro de `{ }`

Answer (score 2):

Esto no tiene ningún sentido en `mysqli`:

```
foreach ($mysqli->query('SELECT * FROM datosprode WHERE resultado = "gana" && fechareg = "05/07/22" ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5 ') as $row)
{ 
    # ¿Qué haces aquí?
}
```

Basta con leer la [documentación sobre `query()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php) y los ejemplos, que explican cómo funciona.

En la documentación queda claramente explicado que las consultas del tipo `SELECT` **retornan un objeto [mysqli_result](https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.mysqli-result.php)**. Es como un recurso con los datos, que tiene sus propios métodos de lectura, son los métodos `fetch_`, que podrás ver en el apartado [**Tabla de contenidos**](https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.mysqli-result.php#class.mysqli-result).

Escribamos un ejemplo basado en uno de esos métodos de lectura: [`fetch_assoc()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) y apliquémoslo a tu contexto:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM datosprode WHERE resultado = 'gana' && fechareg = '05/07/22' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5";
/* Verificar si la consulta trajo datos*/
if ($rs = $mysqli->query($sql)) {
    /* obtener un array asociativo */
    while ($row = $rs->fetch_assoc()) { 
        /*
           Imprimir cada fila / columna
           OJO: Debes cambiar laColumna 
           por un nombre real de columnas
           y puedes imprimir más columnas de tu fila
        */
        printf ("%s\n", $row["laColumna"]);
    }

    /* liberar el conjunto de resultados */
    $rs->free();
} else {
    echo "No se encontraron datos";
}
```

Básicamente, `query()` te devuelve un conjunto de resultados (representado en el código por la variable `$rs`) y tú recorres ese conjunto de resultados fila por fila dentro de un bucle `while`, aplicando un método de lectura, aquí usamos `fetch_assoc`, pero puede ser otro que mejor te convenga. Y, dentro del `while` puedes imprimir los datos, o guardarlos para devolverlos en una llamada a otro contexto...

Si te queda alguna duda, revisa la documentación y los ejemplos y si siguen dudas, pregunta en comentarios debajo de la respuesta. Espero te sirva.

#### Post-Data

Cabe decir que los datos sólo se leen mediante el bucle `while` cuando **esperas más de una fila de resultados**, si esperas una sola fila, basta con aplicar el método `fetch` directamente y te obtendrá esa sola fila. En realidad, lo que ocurre al llamar `fetch` es que el puntero se mueve hacia la primera fila, de modo que `while` va moviendo el puntero hasta agotar todas las filas existentes.

Para más detalles sobre esto puedes consultar el apartado titulado **Ejemplo de obtención de datos** de esta [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/218740/29967) a la pregunta: [¿como regresar datos desde una base a una web, con la sintaxis moderna de PHP7?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/218735/29967).

Puedes consultar también [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/329587/29967) a la pregunta [Error con while](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/329583/29967). Observa el código allí, OP aplicaba primero un `fetch` fuera del `while` y luego abría un `while` aplicando `fetch` de nuevo. Dado que ya había aplicado un `fetch`, el puntero estaba en la segunda fila de resultados y OP se estaba rompiendo el coco sin entender lo que estaba ocurriendo.

Como esos, hay más casos que han ocurrido aquí, de los más variopintos, y todo por no entender algo muy simple: **`query()` devuelve un recurso, y luego debes vaciar ese recurso fila por fila aplicando el método adecuado y usando o no un bucle, según la consulta devuelva una o más filas**.

Dicho eso, hay otros métodos como `fetch_all`que te vacían todo el puntero... pero ese es otro asunto, y `fetch_all` depende de un controlador específico, sin el cual no funciona.